# Сравнительный оборот или причастный?

Tags: синтаксис

Предложение:

> Может  быть, дрогнет, как в зеркало
> впаянный, поплавок.

Я думаю, здесь сравнительный оборот и знаки должны быть так расставлены. Или это причастный оборот, частью которого является сравнительный, и после слова 'зеркало' тоже нужна запятая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оборот "как в зеркало впаянный" считается сравнительным (точнее, он имеет значение уподобления). По структуре это причастный оборот с союзом КАК, то есть сравнительный оборот на основе причастного оборота.

Такие обороты могут обособляться или не обособляться в зависимости от распространенности, семантики, места в предложении, например: Как соломинкой пьёшь мою душу. На будто раскрашенной художником поляне мы увидели множество разных цветов.Но: Проглянет день, как будто поневоле, и скроется за край далёких гор.

В приведенном примере мы имеем распространенный оборот, стоящий между подлежащим и сказуемым, который по семантике является попутным сравнением, **поэтому его лучше обособить.**

Сравнить: если бы не было союза КАК, то причастный оборот перед определяемым словом обособляться не должен.

Comment: Да, действительно, это сравнительный оборот, выраженный причастным оборотом. Поэтому, как отметила Вера, запятые нужны.

Answer (score 0):

**Может быть, дрогнет как в зеркало впаянный поплавок.**

Распространенное определение *перед* определяемым словом, запятые не нужны.